# Mocking of RestTemplate is giving always null

Tags: mockito

I am trying to mock the RestTemplate method through mockito but it always returning null.
mockito code:

```
Mockito.when(template.exchange(ArgumentMatchers.any(), ArgumentMatchers.any(),
                    ArgumentMatchers.<HttpEntity<?>>any(), Mockito.<Class<CountDto>>any()))
                    .thenReturn((ResponseEntity<CountDto>) responseEntity);
```

actual code:

```
ResponseEntity<CountDto> responseEntity = template.exchange(envargs.get("CountURL"),
                                 HttpMethod.GET,getHttpEntity(accessToken), CountDto.class);
```

Please let me know  the issue in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code

```
ResponseEntity<CountDto>) responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(new CountDto(), HttpStatus.OK);

Mockito.when(template.exchange(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.any()))
                .thenReturn(responseEntity);
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. But issue is still there. 
I found the issue, previously the rest template is mocked for the code
ResponseEntity<StatusDTO>responseEntity = emplate.exchange(envVars.get("siteURL") + siteName,HttpMethod.GET, getHttpEntity(accessToken), StatusDTO.class);
it was working fine for this  and for    above one it is not working. if i change the above one with ResponseEntity responseEntity = template.exchange(envargs.get("CountURL") + siteName,HttpMethod.GET,getHttpEntity(accessToken), CountDto.class); it is binding for old one and is there any to way to reset the template